# Creating parallax text

Tags: html, css

hey guys i have seen a parallax website online ,now i have done parallax in the past, but what i am not able to figure out on this website is how a certain parallax text appears on this website .

[website link :](http://amrapalijewels.com/index.php).

The parallax text i am talking about :

[image: The image]

now i asked this question to one of my seniour colleagues and i got the following answer :

> the text is part of the following image :  [Link.](http://amrapalijewels.com/images/eternal_mystery_background_newest.png).

but to me its still unclear how exactly this is created , reading the console too does't explain much .

can somebody give me a vague idea how this parallax text is created ?

**EDIT :: clarification of my question .**

Hey guys , if you have a look at the screen shot i attached and open the website in a tab , you'll see that that perticular peice of text has a parallax background , I.E. while you scroll , the background of the text moves , My question is , how is this done ?

if all you did was have a look at my screen shot and opened the website i had added as a link , you'd clearly see what i was talking about .

anyways , i resolved this issue, **THE ANSWER** to my question can be found here :[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ar7xprs7/).

and as witko added in one of the comments the basic principal of acheiving such an effect is the following :

> You just lay one image on top of the other. PNG images support
>   transparency, so if you cut holes in the top image, the bottom image
>   will be visible through these holes.

the CSS code :

```
body {
    margin:0;
    background-image:url(http://amrapalijewels.com/images/muse-2-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
    background-attachment:fixed;
 }
#container {
    height:1400px;
 }
#mystery {
    height:400px;
    background-image:url(http://amrapalijewels.com/images/eternal_mystery_background_newest.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
 }
@media screen and (max-width:730px) {
body,#mystery {
    background-size:260%;
  }
 }
```

THE HTML code ::

```
<div id="container">

<div id="mystery"></div>

</div>
```

thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: In that website text is transparent and in background use image and it's position change on scroll. following image is used. http://amrapalijewels.com/images/muse-2-bg.jpg in background

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: I cannot speak on behalf of the moderators, but I believe it is because you have not shown any attempt in the question, no code (which a lot of people like to see), nor does it really describe what is happening. I personally would have closed as 'too broad' due to a number of possible ways.

Comment: @jbutler483, Highly appreciate your courage to speak up and be straightforward . I've edited my question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use this image http://amrapalijewels.com/images/muse-2-bg.jpg in the background and the image your colleague said (http://amrapalijewels.com/images/eternal_mystery_background_newest.png) on top of it the one on top is a png with the text cut out so you can see through to the background image. You can use inspect element to see for your self by delete the node

```
<section id="first" class="story first">
```

Edit from @witiko

> You just lay one image on top of the other. PNG images support
>   transparency, so if you cut holes in the top image, the bottom image
>   will be visible through these holes.

Comment: Thanks for trying .. figuring this out , has been a huge pain in the wrong place !

Comment: You just lay one image on top of the other. PNG images support transparency, so if you cut holes in the top image, the bottom image will be visible through these holes.

Comment: @Enjayy , if you edit your question t include the answer i have posted in the question , you have +15 browny points coming from my side !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Yeah sorry about that I didnt explain it very well!
Witiko Thanks for explaining it clearer!